# Does Arrayfire python support multi-GPU programming

Tags: python, concurrent.futures, arrayfire

I am trying to use arrayFire python (https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-python) for multi-GPU programming.

However, when I try to interface it with the concurrent futures (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library, I run into synchronization issues.

Does anyone have inputs on how to use arrayfire-python to parallel process on multiple GPUs ?

Comment: Where is your tested codes? errors if you got?

Answer (score 1):

ArrayFire allows Mutli-GPU programming but does not distribute the work load automatically. It is up to the user to decide which memory and functions run on which device.

ArrayFire as it stands now is NOT thread safe. Hence running anything on multiple threads can cause issues.

Disclosure: I am a developer for ArrayFire.